# How to fix a leak in the wall

Tags: drywall, leak

I seem to have a leak in the wall. I don't think it's plumbing related because it just seems to appear during rainy days. Is there anything I can do before more damage occurs?  Unfortunately it's going to be a rainy week here and these are crazy times given COVID-19 status.  Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: More details: leak is on an East-facing 1st FL wall. No visible signs of leak on 2nd or 3rd floors. Asked neighbor, he denied any leaks.  Wall is shared with another house (row-home style, adjacent house on east wall and west wall).  Roof inspection two months ago didn't reveal any issues (purchased house a month ago).  Roof pictures below, it looks like the leak location coincides with the neighbor's chimeny.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is above the wall?   What is on the other side of the wall?

Comment: @DMoore: On the other side of the wall is another attached home (attached row homes style), and above the wall is another room.  None of the rooms above seem to be having any leaks or signs of it.

Comment: We will need to know a lot more about the structure to even start guessing. Single story, multi story, type of exterior, access a ability to the area above, even the type of roof and if their is a balky above this area.  I use a thermal camera to help identify leaks at the origin sometimes they can travel quite a ways from the actual leak even the internal walls Sheetrock, plaster, stucco. All these things can make a difference.

Comment: So this is an inside wall of a multifamily structure and it has another floor above it.   99% chance if those are true that this is a plumbing issue.    I am guessing there is a bathroom on the other side above, for your neighbor - that is usually how the layouts work for row homes.

Comment: @EdBeal, It's a three-story house with a brick facade and a flat roof. The picture is from the ground floor and there doesn't appear to be any similar damage on the 2nd or 3rd floors in this spot.  There are no balconies in this house.  Above this room is a bedroom.  The house is a row home so there is another house directly on the other side of this wall.  I just spoke to that homeowner and he said he doesn't see any kind of leak.

Comment: @DMoore I just spoke to the homeowner on the other side and he said there's no bathroom there, his bathroom is in the back of the house.  He denied seeing any leaks in his house.

Comment: Well you have a really odd issue if there is no bathroom or kitchen above you.   That is actually bad news.   Now you have to track down how the leak got to your first floor.   I find it very very hard to believe that a shared wall doesn't have plumbing in it for a bathroom or kitchen.    It would be very very odd for this leak be a leak in the roof but it can happen.   Do you have pictures of your roofline?

Comment: I do have pictures of our roof, we did a roof inspection right before purchasing this home, which we purchased a month ago. The guy said the roof looks like it's about 5 years old, no issues with it.

Comment: This stinks a common wall for several floors above , may be worth renting a thermal camera to see if you can track the leak without opening the walls , since it occurs with rain it could be coming from the roof and finds its way inside at this location dribbling down the walls. I have a FLIR one pro I use with my I phone , I have the older FLIR one and they are great for tracking heat or cold through walls, I mostly use mine for electrical but tracking a leak that was on a roof a long way horizontally from where the leak showed up I use this right away now, the water shows as cold streaks.

Comment: @EdBeal: interesting, I'll take a look. I attached photos of the room as well. It looks like the location of the leak coincides with the location of the neighbor's chimney, but just eyeballing it. Not sure if exact.

Comment: Ahhh - chimney makes perfect sense.   I am guessing that the water is traveling along framing and has no where to go when it hits your first floor.   Guessing that this leak is effecting the second floor too but it hasn't shown...   I am guessing this kind of repair is HOA?

Comment: A chimney would be a good area to check. Note I have no connection to the FLIR camera or stock in them, I have saved my self and company much more than the cost of the camera and upgraded to the pro. There are less expensive options but this has helped me in the past when I could not find the leak visually.

Comment: @DMoore and Ed: thanks so much for your helpful comments. Unfortunately no HOA, these are single family attached townhouses. I got in touch with a roofer and thankfully he can come by tomorrow even during these crazy times. Hopefully this can all be resolved pretty quickly without much damage.  Again I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @DMoore and Ed: I got a roofer to come and we both went up on the roof to investigate. The issue is indeed near the chimney there are small cracks that need to be fixed.  Do you guys happen to know how I could fix the damage to the dry wall inside? Is it as simple as sand + repaint?

Comment: @David - It need to be scraped out, mudded, feathered/sanded, primed, repaint.   Repaint that area and go out an extra 2' on each side.

Comment: @DMoore: do you think I need to remove the crown molding to make sure there's no moisture stuck underneath? That sounds like overkill to me, and possibly something I can't do myself... My wife and I are expecting and a friend told me there might be mold if there's moisture stuck there...

Comment: I wouldn't.   Yes there might be damage behind there but it is of no consequence if the molding is there.   Taking that off and you are sure to damage the molding and other parts of the wall.   As for "water issues"... if things are bad and mold grows you have to take wall apart, the molding is the last thing you will worry about.   The hardest thing you have to do is flatten the touch up mud you use - which should be feathered out over 12" and then trying to lightly match the paint.   You are going to have to do a light coat of primer or by paint/primer...

Comment: @DMoore: again, thanks so much. your feedback is invaluable!